# Why append() is called every loop?

Tags: python, pyglet

I have got the tile class:

```py
class Tile:
    tile_pref = {
        "sprites": []
    }
    pos = Vector2(vector_zero)

    def img(self, x, y, tilemap, t):
        return self.tile_pref["sprites"][0]

    def __init__(self, img, pos):
        self.tile_pref["sprites"].append(img)
        self.pos = pos
```

And another part, cropped:
`src` is valid string path, `spacing`, `tile_size`, `offset` are vectors with `.x` and `.y`.
`self.__tiles__` is array.

```py
img = pyglet.image.load(src)
for i in range((img.height - offset.x) // (spacing.x + tile_size.x) + 1):
  for j in range((img.width - offset.y) // (spacing.y + tile_size.y) + 1):
                a = offset.x + (tile_size.x + spacing.x) * j
                b = offset.y + (tile_size.y + spacing.y) * i
                self.__tiles__.append(Tile(img.get_region(a, b, tile_size.x, tile_size.y), Vector2(i, j)))
```

Main problem is in what `tile_pref["sprites"]` is not `1` in length, bu equals to all amount of tiles. How can I fix it?

---

I think, when I call `img.get_region`, it returns me a link to it. So, it calls `append` any time link is changing.

Comment: @Rabbid76: "Main problem is in what tile_pref["sprites"] is not 1 in length, bu equals to all amount of tiles." The question is very unclear in it's formulation indeed, but the issue is obvious just reading the class definition xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
class Tile:
    tile_pref = {
        "sprites": []
    }
    pos = Vector2(vector_zero)
```

You are defining `tile_pref` and `pos` as *class* attributes - attributes that belong to the class (not to the instances of...), and are shared amongst all instances. Unless shadowed by an instance attribute, class attributes are also available thru the instance (which is how you can access methods, which ARE class attributes), so here:

```
def __init__(self, img, pos):
    self.tile_pref["sprites"].append(img)
```

you are actually mutating the class's own `tile_pref` attribute - so whatever you add here will be visible to all instances.

Note that the following line:

```
    self.pos = pos
```

creates a 'pos' *instance* attribute (you are binding the name, not mutating), which will shadow the class attribute.

For what it's worth, **all this is [clearly and explicitely documented](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) in the official tutorial** - so I kindly suggest you stop what you're doing, take a day (or two if needed) to do the **whole** tutorial, then come back to your code. This will save you a **lot** of time and pain and frustration.